# Android Multiple Level[3] Expandable List View

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I tried to implement a expandable list view with 3 levels, this was implemented using http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/09/three-level-expandable-list.html example. But here, I couldn't open the last item. When I open it,  child items of this were hidden by below item.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJki4.png)

Please see the attachment.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: if you have another solution please post it here.

Comment: You can refer to my github sample code https://github.com/ngocchung/ThreeLevelExpListView